# Wait for future get result in a handler thread

Tags: java, android, concurrency, handler

I have three tasks that i submit to a executor instance. I need to  notify two activities that the sync process is over. So I have achieved it like this

> public class SyncManager {
>
> ```
> Handler syncHandler;
>
> public SyncManager() {
>     initHandler();
> }
>
> private void initHandler() {
>     HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("syncHandler");
>     ht.start();
>     syncHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper()) {
>         private ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
>
>         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
>
>             Future future1 = executor.submit(new ImageRetrieverTask());
>             Future future2 = executor.submit(new FileRetrieverTask());
>             Future future3 = executor.submit(new AudioRetrieverTask());
>
>
>             try {
>                 Object result1 = future1.get();
>                 Object result2 = future2.get();
>                 Object result3 = future3.get();
>
>       // Here i can use EventBus to notify observers of the completion of the sync
>             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             } catch (ExecutionException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         };
>     };
> }
>
> public void performSync() {
>     syncHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
> } }
> ```

When the SyncManager class is allocated, the handler is initialised.
When the performSync method is called it basically sends a message to the handler to add all the sync related tasks to the executor so that it can execute them. The handler is the background loop that waits till the futures are over so that a notification can be dispatched through the EventBus. A handler is so that i can do the wait in the background thread.

I feel like this is a hacky way of doing this. Is there a better way of doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: it's common to use Rxjava for this kind of task. Refer to this blog for more detail: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/getting-started-with-rxjava-and-android

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not use `Future` results and do not reuse `ThreadPoolExecutor` you may wait until all the submitted tasks are completed by invoking `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`